# User interface issues regarding embedded PDFs

Tags: user-interface, pdf, cross-browser

**Q.1.** What are the advantages and disadvantages, from a usability standpoint, of embedding PDFs in a web page?

**Q.2.** In general, for the average computer user, which scenario provides the most "streamlined" experience?

**Q.3.** Would using cookies to remember the options substantially improve Scenario #2?

#### Scenario #1

1. User sets options.
2. User clicks a **Report** button.
3. PDF is sent as an attachment (to Save or Open).

Advantages

- The options don't get reset.

Disadvantages

- The PDF can obstruct the web page.
- The user might leave too many PDF windows open (slowing system performance).

#### Scenario #2

1. User sets options.
2. User clicks a Report button.
3. PDF is embedded in the page.
4. User clicks back and the options will have been reset (AJAX, no cookies).

Advantages

- The results appear immediately (no extra clicks).

Disadvantages

- Not all browsers support embedding PDFs (?).
- The web page (i.e., the **Report** button) disappears.

Thank you!

Comment: You should describe what you mean by 'embed'.  Generally, if a PDF is referenced in a web page, its up to the brower and its settings whether or not to display it within the web brower, or to shell out to a PDF viewer.

Comment: Right... but you said you *were* embedding and didnt indicate how - so there's no way to effectively answer your question. I still think your best bet is to link to the PDF, and let the end user decide if they want it embedded or not via their browser/pdf viewer settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *hate* when a pdf opens in a browser window. But I'm one data point, and one that's probably not interesting to you. What you need to do is talk to your actual customers and ask them instead.

Without more details it's just too hard to say what is best for your specific application. Do users use your app 8 hours a day, or only 8 minutes a month? Do they typically have large screens? Small? Do they access the app via mobile devices? Is viewing the report their primary job activity, or is the report something they'll print and shove in a drawer? Answer these questions and the answer to your usability question will be easier to get.

The bottom line is, ask your users. If you can't, or the answer is indeterminate, give them both options and let them choose.

Comment: +1 for the "I hate it when a pdf opens in a browser window" and the "talk to your actual customers and ask them instead".

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be best to avoid embedding the PDF at all. If this purpose is to preview the data on the report, would it be possible to display an image of the first page of the PDF? Alternatively, if the purpose is to preview the data in the PDF, it might be easier to display the data as HTML. Either way, I think it would be better to use HTML or images (which load faster and more consistently across browsers) to preview the PDF and then offer a download link.

Comment: +1 If the user needs a .PDF, let them download it manually. If they just want to look at the result, render it in HTML or as an image (there are plenty of PDF->image libraries out there).

Comment: @Computerish: The PDF is too complex for either an image or HTML page. Also, it needs to fit 8.5 x 11 for printing purposes.

Comment: If it's a report, and it's that complex, perhaps there's a fundamental issue with the formatting and contents of the report (Granted, I assume that's completely out of your hands)

Comment: @DA: I have full control over the formatting and contents of the report. Take a look at the link, generate a report, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I don't see why you can't display a sample image. Just take a sample image and scale it down to a reasonable size. The text doesn't have to be readable, you just have to be able to see the formatting and what the chart looks like. When the user wants to really dive into the data, they can download the whole PDF and use any viewer they want.

Comment: @Computerish: The text must be readable. The result must have links that can be clicked (e.g., the city name). It's not just about the chart; the chart is meaningless without the content. The chart must be printer-friendly (including embedded fonts). The issue isn't about alternative ways to present the data, the issue is: should it be an embedded PDF or opened externally?

Answer (score 2):

This is a question perfect for UX Exchange:

http://uxexchange.com/

To answer the question, I'd step back first. We're talking PDFs. The format, alone, is going to be causing usability and accessibility issues.

Keep in mind:

- not everyone uses acrobat reader
- not everyone uses pdf plugins
- not every browser supports pdf plugins

Bottom line, get it out of a PDF to begin with.

Otherwise, if the format is required, surrender to default rather than embed, IMHO. I'd do one of two things:

1) send it to the browser as a PDF (letting the browser settings decide what to do with it)

2) generate the PDF and then provide a link to it

Comment: @DA: PDF is absolutely required; I need full control over how the print version looks (font, size, layout, embedded chart, etc.). Keeping the PDF server-side is a good idea, but requires monitoring drive space and setting up a cron task to delete old files. It also involves an extra step for the user: to click a link.

Comment: @DA: uxechange is nice, but having to register and update profiles 15 gazillion times (once per SO copy) gets annoying quite quickly.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: have you looked at linking the accounts? On a "new" SO site you just log in with your current SO open-id. The site will notice that it hasn't been used there yet and offer to register for you. Accounts are thus linked and I think automatically updated as well. You even get 100 bonus rep if your current account has  more than 200 rep.

Comment: +1 for letting the browser decide what to do with the pdf. The browser will have been setup according to the individual users' preferences and this ensures that you follow those instead of being the odd one out.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: Sorry, I just had a look at uxexchange and it turns out it uses open-id, but it doesn't seem to be in the SO or stackechange family - and does not auto-pick-up your profile which SO-family-member sites do.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend against the "button" approach and allow your users to decide what they want by simply presenting a link (e.g. `<a href="...">link</a>`) to a download without a `Content-Disposition` header with a prominent PDF "icon".

This will allow everyday users to either:

1. Left click the link and allow their browser preferences interpret the link as they normally do (be that in Adobe Reader in the browser, prompt for download, browser extension, etc).
2. Right click the link and choose to "Save As...". Perhaps a friendly `div` could appear when hovering over this link recommending to users that if they wish to download the PDF, they should right click and choose "Save As")

A form button (which is what I assume you are considering above) doesn't allow this right click option.

In my experience, people hate the "surprise" of a PDF opening in their browser without warning. Power-users are typically the ones most annoyed by this and have configured their browsers to handle this or are used to "right clicking" links to these kinds of files (when they know they are coming).

Answer (score 0):

How about scenario #3?

1. User sets options.
2. User clicks a Report button.
3. PDF appears in an IFRAME embedded in the page.
4. options stay in place

This would combine the advantages of the two: The options won't be reset; There will be only one PDF instance open at any given time (except for power users with multiple tabs, but they have to know what they're doing.)

You could also offer a separate direct download for experienced users.

Comment: The PDF is quite large: 8.5 x 11, so there is no screen real estate left to display both the PDF and the options, without having to scroll the page. That is tantamount to hiding options. An interesting idea, though.

Comment: @Dave why not try and use jQuery tabs or something to switch between the embedded PDF and the options?

Comment: jQuery tabs with multiple forms don't mix. The idea of switching between PDF and options, though, is interesting.